# Check cell for letters, if not found run function in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using this code to check whether a cell is not empty. If it is not empty the next function runs etc etc.

However, I would like to modify the code so it searches for specific letters in the cell.

The data in the cell may be similar to M35, W40 or F20-39 and many variations. I need to search for the M, W and F. If those letters are NOT present then the function should run. If they Are present then the else function should run.

Thank you in advance for any help with this.

```
      function checkT2() {
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var cell = sh.getRange("T2").getValue();

      //check if cell is not empty
      if (cell) {
      SplitNames();
      } else {
      fullNames();
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkT2() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sh.getRange("T2").getValue();
  if (cell && (cell.slice(0,1)=='M' || cell.slice(0,1)=='W' || cell.slice(0,1)=='F')) {
    SplitNames();
  } else {
    fullNames();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You want to run the function of `SplitNames()` when the value of `cell` is `M35`, `W40` or `F20-39` and many variations.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification point:

- In this modification, `test()` is used. For this, the regular expression of `[MWF][\d-]+` is used.

In order to reflect this to your script, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
if (cell) {
```

#### To:

```
if (/[MWF][\d-]+/.test(cell)) {
```

#### Note:

- If more sample values are provided, I think that the regular expression might be able to be modified.

#### Reference:

- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.